# What is the allowed size of a youtube channel name?

Tags: youtube, min, youtube-channels

What is the allowed size of a YouTube channel name (minimal length - maximal length)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google account name size limits are here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/faq#login_limits
YouTube channel names are limited to 20, case insensitive, alphanumeric characters.

I believe the minimum length is 6 characters. I have a vague memory of watching a Randall Munroe presentation at Google where he complained that he couldn't obtain the xkcd gmail username because it was too short.

Comment: also note usernames can contain alphanumeric, underscore, dash, apostrophe, period.  http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33386

Comment: As of April 2020, the max length has been increased to 30 characters per the [YouTube API developer docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels)

Comment: Just a reminder to everyone reading this comment, keep in mind that it's 10 years old (at the time I'm writing mine). The limits changed multiple times since then. Currently, the limit is 50 characters, but there's no guarantee that it's not going to change again. Maybe it might be wise to reserve some 100 characters for a string like this in your database and not limit it to anything below that (that doesn't mean resigning on other forms of validation).

Comment: Since handles have been introduced at the end of 2022 (and you can be sure all channels have a handle since 14th November), the minimum length is now 3 characters, with the maximum length at 30 chars. For more information, see https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/11585688

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of a Youtube username is 36 characters.

Answer (score -2):

YouTube Channel with the longest name: youtube.com/channel/UCw-obQfCN1GK1y8VKL78IZw
YouTube Channel with long Rick Roll name: youtube.com/channel/UCngw0n0HK2p_ku4hn43WhWw
Longest name on Silver Play Button: youtube.com/watch?v=GhtJnFfj_3Y

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).