# Youtube and Twitch channel name maximum character limit

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, twitch

I am trying to find docs to figure out what the max limit is for YouTube and twitch channel names, but I am unable to find one.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300655/what-is-the-allowed-size-of-a-youtube-channel-name) suggests it's 20 but this post is like 3 years old. Plus the official YouTube API page doesn't list anything like that. Does anyone know what the limits are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the YouTube V3 API, when creating a new channel, your channel name comes from your Google Account name:

> First and last names support unicode/UTF-8 characters, with a maximum of 60 characters.

[Name and password guidelines](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en)

The API docs only explicitly disclose the maximum number of characters for a [video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet) title (100) and a [channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet) description (1000).

I don't believe this information is available for Twitch through their API.

Answer (score 2):

### Twitch

As per [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitch/comments/32w5b2/username_requirements/), as well as [this post on the Twitch Developer Forums](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/max-length-for-user-names-and-display-names/21315):

- **4 to 25 characters**
- letters, numbers, underscores

To quote the reddit answer, valid usernames seem to be defined by the folliwing regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,25}$
```

Note:

- Neither sources are official docs, but both seem reasonably credible
- Usernames on Twitch equal channel names but are different from Display Names

Answer (score 0):

According to what YouTube allows me in 2022, it's 50 characters now.